# Derivation of Heisenberg-Langevin equations for an atom coupled to a reservoir of harmonic oscillators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, noise, brownian-motion

I have been working on the paper of A. Lezama on the ["Numerical investigation of the quantum fluctuations..."](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.77.013806) (2008) and been trying to replicate their derivation and simulation. However, I encounter some problems with the derivation of the Heisenberg-Langevin - or quantum Langevin - equation (eq. 5 in the paper).

I would like to understand first a simpler case where we only consider a two-level atomic system coupled to a reservoir of electromagnetic modes. My problem essentially comes from the fact that in most textbooks ([Atom—Photon Interactions by Claude Cohen-Tannoudji](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9783527617197) Complement C.IV.2 and [Quantum Optics by Marlan O. Scully](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-optics/08DC53888452CBC6CDC0FD8A1A1A4DD7) Chapter 9) the system coupled is a harmonic oscillator which leads to a Langevin force expression depending only on the reservoir operators at the initial time. This is mostly a consequence of $ \left[ 
        \hat{\sigma}(t), \hat{\sigma}^\dagger(t) 
    \right] = 1$ which is not the case for a two-level system.

Writing down the whole derivation would be too long for this question so I kept the main steps to give you a glance at what I have done:
[image]

Equation 17 shows a force depending on the atomic system, which cannot lead to a Langevin force according to my understanding since it should be "external" and random (i.e not depending on the current state of our system).

I hope I have been able to clearly state my problem, I can try my best to reformulate if necessary.
Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Your Langevin force is external and random... but it is *multiplicative* rather than *additive*. Compare, e.g., to $\dot{x}=f(x,t) + g(x,t)\xi(t)$, where $\xi(t)$ is a random Gaussian noise

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So how can prove that the expected value of the force is null over the state of the reservoir? When I write the expected value I don't know how to deal with sigma(t) since - because of the coupling - it is also acting the "reservoir Hilbert space".

Comment: ($ \sigma(t)$ has no reason to commute with $a(t_0)$)

Comment: You can just take the average of the force over the state of the reservoir - averaging $a(t_0)$ will give you zero (except for some special choices of the reservoir state.)

Comment: Yes, the average $\langle a(t_0) \rangle = 0$ over the reservoir but I can't decouple the expectations value of $\sigma(t)$ and $a(t_0)$ in $\langle a(t_0) \sigma(t) \sigma^\dagger(t) \rangle$ since they don't commute. The states $\vert \psi \rangle$ (of the reservoir) and $\vert \psi' \rangle = a(t_0) \sigma(t) \sigma^\dagger(t) \vert \psi \rangle$ could potentially overlap, leading to a non-null average no? Will it be compensated by the other term $-\langle a(t_0) \sigma(t)^\dagger \sigma(t) \rangle$? If it's the case I don't clearly see why